# Пропорциональное растягивание изображения

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как растягивать изображение по ширине и высоте так что-бы оно всегда было на 100% ширины и высоты страницы (или до заданного размера).
Результат должен выглядеть примерно так:
https://unsplash.com/photos/bEbwgH6wP6Y
Если есть какие-то скрипты для этого или общие советы,то буду рад выслушать.

Comment: див с вашим рисунком, бек {height: 100%;
    width: 100%; background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1459698180825-593f300f4a1e?crop=entropy&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1325");}

Answer (score 1):

```
body{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
div{
background-image: url("images.unsplash.com/…) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
width: 100% !important;
height: 100% !important;
}
```